# How can I perform the same set of commands separately for each file in the same file path?

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to deal with extracting a subset from multiple .grb2 files in the same file path, and write them in a csv. I am able to do it for one (or a few) by using the following set of commands:

```
GRIB <- brick("tmp2m.1989102800.time.grb2")
GRIB <- as.array(GRIB)
readGDAL("tmp2m.1989102800.time.grb2")
tmp2m.6hr <- GRIB[51,27,c(261:1232)]
str(tmp2m.6hr)
tmp2m.data <- data.frame(tmp2m.6hr)
write.csv(tmp2m.data,"tmp1.csv")
```

The above set of commands extract, in csv, temperature values for specific latitude "51" and longitude "27", as well as for a specific time range "c(261:1232)".

Now I have hundreds of these files (with different file names, of course) in the same directory and I want to do the same for all. As you know, better than me, I cannot do this to one by one, changing the file name each time.

I have struggled a lot with this, but so far I did not manage to do it. Since I am new in R, and my knowledge is limited, I would very much appreciate any possible help with this.

Comment: look at `list.files` and apply your code to each file in a `for` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use a normal for loop:

```
path <- "your file path here"
input.file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".grb2")
output.file.names <- paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(file.names),".csv")
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
  GRIB <- brick(input.file.names[i])
  GRIB <- as.array(GRIB)
  readGDAL(input.file.names[i]) # edited line
  tmp2m.6hr <- GRIB[51,27,c(261:1232)]
  str(tmp2m.6hr)
  tmp2m.data <- data.frame(tmp2m.6hr)
  write.csv(tmp2m.data,output.file.names[i])
}
```

You could of course create the body of the for loop into a function and then use the standard `lapply` or the `map` function from purrr.

Note that this code will print out different CSV files. If you want to append the data to a single file then you should check out [write.table](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot Harvey! with slight modifications, this works perfectly fine. readgdal creates an error for some reason, so I removed it. This did not make any difference, at least for I want to do.

Comment: @K.Kaf ah yeah - that is a file name - you would need to put one of the dynamic file names from the list there too! I will make an edit!

Comment: You’re welcome. Would you be able to accept that as the answer please (the tick underneath my answer) so we can close this one out. Thanks.

Comment: Harvey Ellis, I posted another question which constitutes a sequence of this one. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106376/how-can-i-write-multiple-csv-files-in-a-specific-directory-and-then-merge-them-i