# How can I write multiple csv files in a specific directory and then merge them into a single csv?

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to deal with extracting a subset from multiple .grb2 files in the same file path, and write them in separate csv files. I am using the following code which does the job and stores the csv files in the same directory as the .grb2 files.

```
path <- "file path"
input.file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".grb2")
output.file.names <- 
paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(input.file.names),".csv")
for(i in 1:length(input.file.names)){
  GRIB <- brick(input.file.names[i])
  GRIB <- as.array(GRIB)
  tmp2m.6hr <- GRIB[46,13,c(1:20)]
  str(tmp2m.6hr)
  tmp2m.data <- data.frame(tmp2m.6hr)
  write.csv(tmp2m.data,output.file.names[i])
}
```

My first question is this: how can I store the csv files in a different directory than the .grb2 files?
My .grb2 files, and thus the resulting csv files, end in four different types, i.e. 00.grb2, 06.grb2, 12.grb2, 18.grb2. The resulting csv files have the following form:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le1Wt.jpg)

My second question is: how can I merge all my 00.csv, 06.csv, 12.csv, 18.csv files (each category in the same column) in a single csv file in a directory of my choice with the following headrs: 00_tmp2m.6hr, 06_tmp2m.6hr, 12_tmp2m.6hr, 18_tmp2m.6hr, and also create a fifth column with the average of the other four? The result that I want is the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUQax.jpg)

As I m not an experienced user this is too complicated for me. I would very much apreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 1):

For your fist question, you might try specifying the path using a relative reference to the folder, as in `write.csv(paste0("./myfolder/", output.file.names[i]))`.

Your second question might be easier if you read the data and then write your results as a new file. you might also want to take a look at the optional parameters of `write.csv(append = FALSE, ...)`.

Also, you might get a better answer by creating a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).